# a faster way to achieve what intersect() is giving me?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, intersection

I am finding that a **lot** of time spent in my matlab function is in this code:

```
intersect(freq_bins, our_bins);
```

Both can be rather large vectors, and are comprised of only integers.  I just need to know which integers are in both.  This is truly the primitive purpose of intersect(), so I suspect that the answer is: it doesn't get any better.  But maybe someone has some suggestions.

Comment: 1) It's "composed of" not "comprised of" :) 2) In principle,  intersecting unsorted lists would take O(N^2), but intersecting sorted lists would take O(N). Sorting itself would be O(Nlog(N)), so as @Jonas says, you could do it better yourself with sorted vectors.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: the main reason for speed gain in this case is that you can avoid overhead from input checking as well as from calling multiple functions.

Comment: @Jonas: I'm sure you're right. My favorite example is the LAPACK routine DGEMM for multiplying / scaling matrices. One would expect it to be optimized to the nth degree, but unless the matrices are pretty big, it spends a large fraction of its time calling LSAME, to classify its input flags. Its real goal is to save coding work for the programmer, not necessarily speed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`intersect` calls `ismember`. In your case, you don't need all the complicated checks that `intersect` does, so you can save some overhead and call `ismember` directly (note: I made sure to call both functions before timing them):

```
a = randi(1000,100,1);
b = randi(1000,100,1);

>> tic,intersect(a,b),toc
ans =
    76
   338
   490
   548
   550
   801
   914
   930
Elapsed time is 0.027104 seconds.

>> tic,a(ismember(a,b)),toc
ans =
   914
   801
   490
   548
   930
   550
    76
   338
Elapsed time is 0.000613 seconds.
```

You can make this even faster by calling `ismembc`, the function that does the actual testing, directly. Note that `ismembc` requires sorted arrays (so you can drop the sort if your input is sorted already!)

```
tic,a=sort(a);b=sort(b);a(ismembc(a,b)),toc
ans =
    76
   338
   490
   548
   550
   801
   914
   930
Elapsed time is 0.000473 seconds.
```

Comment: awesome, man! i sincerely appreciated the response.  Both of my vectors are already guaranteed to be sorted.  Just sped up my runtime by 30% :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that your inputs contain sorted lists of unique integers, then you can do this in linear time with a very simple algorithm:

```
function c = intersect_sorted(a,b)
  ia = 1;
  na = length(a);
  ib = 1;
  nb = length(b);
  ic = 0;
  cn = min(na,nb);
  c = zeros(1,cn);

  while (ia <= na && ib <= nb)
    if (a(ia) > b(ib))
      ib = ib + 1;
    elseif a(ia) < b(ib)
      ia = ia + 1;
    else % a(ia) == b(ib)
      ic = ic + 1;
      c(ic) = a(ia);
      ib = ib + 1;
      ia = ia + 1;
    end
  end
  c = c(1:ic);
end
```

The max runtime for lists of length n and m will be O(n+m).

```
>>a = unique(randi(1000,100,1));
>>b = unique(randi(1000,100,1));
>>tic;for i = 1:10000, intersect(a,b); end,toc
Elapsed time is 1.224514 seconds.
>> tic;for i = 1:10000, intersect_sorted(a,b); end,toc
Elapsed time is 0.289075 seconds.
```