# faster way to achieve unique() in matlab if assumed 1d pre-sorted vector?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, unique

I had good luck finding a way to [achieve intersect() faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159449/a-faster-way-to-achieve-what-intersect-is-giving-me) on stack overflow with a pre-sorted 1d vector, so I am hoping for the same luck for unique() ;)

Almost 1/4'th of my runtime is spent using unique().  I would like to speed this up, and I can assume it to be 1d pre-sorted vector.  Is there any other low-level functions I can use directly to speed this up?

Comment: Can you add a pointer to your intersect question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `diff` to check whether consecutive elements are the same.

```
vector = [1 2 3 4 4 5];

uniqueVector = vector([true;diff(vector(:))>0])

uniqueVector =
     1     2     3     4     5
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested a little bit, using sort + diff, it's slightly faster than the original "unique" function in matlab.

Comment: how about something similar for cell array ? say, vector = {'a1', 'a1', 'b2'};

Comment: @user702846 in that case you should write the answer as an anonymous function and call it using the cellfun function