# Matlab: searching arrays for similar values and create a new array containing all values

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

I have three column vectors:

```
A = [1;2;5;9;15]
B = [2;3;5;11;15]
C = [5;7;11;20;25]
```

I want to create a new column vector `D` by searching through all the elements of `A` `B` `C`, finding all the values and avoid repeating them in `D`.

I want `D` to be:

```
D = 
    1
    2
    3
    5
    7
    9
    11
    15
    20
    25
```

How to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: `unique([A;B;C])`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [faster way to achieve unique() in matlab if assumed 1d pre-sorted vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174578/faster-way-to-achieve-unique-in-matlab-if-assumed-1d-pre-sorted-vector)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way than using matlab built-in 'unique'?

Comment: Look at the suggested duplicate post - it contains a method which does not use `unique`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another (super-fast) way, not using `unique`, and no loops, if you are dealing only with integers:

```
A = [1;2;5;9;15];
B = [2;3;5;11;15];
C = [5;7;11;20;25];
tmp = [A;B;C]; % concat the vectors
R = min(tmp):max(tmp)+1; % the range of the values
ind = histcounts(tmp,R)>0; % find all elements within tmp
D = R(ind).' % extract the relevant values
```

This method could be generalized for doubles:

```
A = [1.2;2.62;5.74;9.29;15.31];
B = [2.3;3;5;9.29;15.31];
C = [1.2;2.62;11;20;25];
tmp = sort([A;B;C]); % concat and sort the vectors
R = [tmp; max(tmp)+1]; % the range of the values
ind = histcounts(tmp,R)>0; % find all elements within tmp
D = tmp(ind) % extract the relevant values
```

However, the need to sort the values first (in `tmp`) makes it slower than the other methods.

Comment: @user5916581 You may find some other techniques [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941694/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: This method seems to require integer values. However if this is wanted, then the method seems to have good performance.

Comment: @patrik I have added a generalized method, but it seems to outperform the other methods only with integers.

Comment: I would assume this has to do with the call to `sort()`. Normally sorting methods are heavy. In best cases you might come down to a O(n*log(n)) operation, but worst case is many times O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want:

```
% Your sample arrays
A=[1;2;5;9;15]
B=[2;3;5;11;15]
C=[5;7;11;20;25]

% [A,B,C] concatenates the arrays to one single array
% Unique finds unqiues values in the input array
[D, IA, ID] = unique([A,B,C]);

disp(D);

% D = array with unique values

% ID = array with unique natural number assigned to equal values for the
% original array

% IA = array that can be referenced against ID to find the value in the
% original array

% ID and IA can be used to recreate the original array
```

Solution without using "unique", this is probably less efficient:

```
% SOLUTION WITHOUT USING UNIQUE

% Your variables
A=[1;2;5;9;15];
B=[2;3;5;11;15];
C=[5;7;11;20;25];

% Allocate a temporary array with your arrays concatenated
temp = sort([A;B;C]);
rep_count = 0; % Count number of repeat values

% Allocate a blank array for your output
D = zeros(length(temp),1);
D(1) = temp(1); % Initialise first element (is always unique)

% Iterate through temp and output unqiue values to D
for i = 2:length(temp)
    if (temp(i) == D(i-1-rep_count))
        rep_count = rep_count+1;
    else
        D(i-rep_count) =  temp(i);
    end
end

% Remove zeros at the end of D
D = D(1:length(D)-rep_count);

disp(D)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way than using matlab built-in 'unique'?

Comment: @user5916581 I edited my solution above with an alternative for you. It is probably  slower than unique...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to sort the data and check the the unique values. This seems to be about as efficient as using the function `unique()`. Possibly with an advantage for using `sort()` and `diff()`. This may however be dependent on hardware and the difference is fairly insignificant, taking into account the simplicity of `D = unique([A;B;C]);`.

```
function test()

% A=[1;2;5;9;15];
% B=[2;3;5;11;15];
% C=[5;7;11;20;25];

A = 500*rand(10000000,1);
B= 500*rand(10000000,1);
C = 500*rand(10000000,1);

f1 = @() testA(A,B,C);
f2 = @() testB(A,B,C);

time1 = timeit(f1,1);
time2 = timeit(f2,1);
disp(time1);
disp(time2);

function D = testA(A,B,C)
d = sort([A;B;C]);
idx = diff(d);
D = d([1;idx]>0);

function D = testB(A,B,C)
D = unique([A;B;C]);
```

test

1.9085

1.9968

Comment: I have tested this on my computer in compare to the [use of `histcounts`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38954226/2627163) (`testC`), the results:   `testA` =  1.6110, `testB` = 1.5125, `testC` = 0.1835